# How to hide dynamic function symbols when using the pimpl idiom in C++?

Tags: c++, gcc, visibility

Assume one has a standard pimpl implementation.

```
// HPP FILE
class Foo{
private:
    class FooImpl;
    std::unique_ptr<FooImpl> pImpl;
public:
    void FunctionFoundInHppFile();
}

// CPP FILE
#include "foo.hpp"

class Foo::FooImpl{
   FunctionNotFoundInHppFile() {};
   FunctionFoundInHppFile() {};
}

Foo::Foo() : pImpl { std::make_unique<FooImpl>() ) {}

void Foo::FunctionFoundInHppFile(){
    pImpl->FunctionFoundInHppFile();
}
```

Using the visibility=hidden flag everything is missing, making it useless. So I compile without it.

```
g++ -fPIC -c Foo.cpp
g++ -shared -o libfoo.so Foo.o
```

For looking into the symbol table I'm doing the following:

```
nm -D libfoo.so
```

Which outputs

```
0000000000134006 W _ZN12Foo16FooImpl10FunctionFoundInHppFileEv
0000000000128474 W _ZN12Foo16FooImpl11FunctionNotFoundInHppFileEv
```

I've tried the following:

```
strip --strip-symbol=FooImpl libfoo.so
```

and

```
strip --strip-unneeded libFoo.so
```

But that didn't do anything.

Is there a way to keep FunctionNotFoundInHppFile from being exposed in the dynamic symbol table?

Comment: C++ doesn't define anything related to symbol visibility, this is a platform or compiler specific question. For GCC consider reading https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility

Comment: There are two functions called `FunctionFoundInHppFile`, can you clarify?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks, that has what I'm looking for.